# WhatsApp Android returns video/x.looping_mp4 as a mime type from EditorInfo - what's that?

Tags: android, whatsapp, ime

I'm building an Android Input Method Editor (IME) and I'm using `EditorInfo.contentMimeTypes` to determine the various mime types that an editor supports. WhatsApp returns `video/x.looping_mp4` as a supported mime type, but I'm having trouble finding any information about what this format is (how to create, etc). Does anyone know of documentation for this format or can anyone shed more light in general on what it is? Thanks!

Comment: It's probably an animated "GIF" that's not technically a GIF but an MP4

Comment: The issue is that, when I try to send an mp4, a toast pops up from WhatsApp saying that the file format is not supported. There's not much more information than that. It'd be helpful if there were a public API (like their sticker one: https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/tree/main/Android), but I can't find anything...